# Project Euler #19 in Java

Tags: java, project

You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.

```
1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
Thirty days has September,
April, June and November.
All the rest have thirty-one,
Saving February alone,
Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
And on leap years, twenty-nine.
A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
```

How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

Solution :

My following logic gives me 173 Sundays , whereas there are 171 Sundays !! Where are the extra 2 days came from ?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Date startDate = new Date(1901, Calendar.JANUARY, 01);
    Date endDate = new Date(2000, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31);

    checkSundays(startDate, endDate);
}

private static void checkSundays(Date start, Date end) {
    int dayNum;

    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startDate.setTime(start);
    System.out.println(startDate.getTime());

    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.setTime(end);
    System.out.println(endDate.getTime());
    int count = 0;

    while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
            dayNum = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            if (dayNum == 1) {
                count++;
            }

            System.out.println(startDate.getTime());
            startDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        }
            System.out.println("Count " + count);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Date` constructor is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your following code uses deprecated constructor of `Date`

```
Date startDate = new Date(1901, Calendar.JANUARY, 01);
System.out.println(startDate);
```

which is not proper, it prints

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 3801
```

So use `Calendar` to construct `Date`,

```
    Calendar startDateCal = createDateInstance(0,1901,1)

    Calendar endDateCal = createDateInstance(11,2000,13)
```

and a Factory method

```
public static Date createDateInstance(int month, int year, int date){
  Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
  cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
  cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);

  return cal.getTime();

}
```

See [your working code](http://ideone.com/AdINY)

Comment: The `Calendar` class uses months going from 0 to 11, so that looks incorrect to me. If there's some justification I'm not seeing though, feel free to provide it.

Comment: +1 Would using the month constants be more readable, e.g. `set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY)`?

Comment: Thank you so much Joshi.... I also noticed that my date was not printing correctly ..but could not find the right way to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use probability and do this with just a calculator.

There's 100 years in a century, and every year, there are 12 first days of the months. Divide that by 7 and you have your answer.

It's cheap, but it works.

Comment: This doesn't actually work... The answer depends on which century and what your start/end dates are.